# Issue with routing rules in GCP Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have 2 backend buckets and I have defined routing rule in my LB as you can see in the image attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWqT9.png)

I want to route to "testing" backend bucket as default route and if url contains /student then I want it to route to another backend bucket "student-cloud-storage".

I have already setuped these things in my LB but when I am trying to reach to /student url it is giving me 404 error

any help regarding this will be appreciated thank you and this is my first question so, let me know if I need to improve anything in the question or any other details

Answer (score 0):

You will need to validate the URL map configuration that you previously configured to ensure that the URL map is routing requests to the appropriate backend as intended. This option isn't available in the UI but you may follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#validate-url-map) as a guide. You will be also asked to provide a YAML file that looks like this.

```
defaultService: /projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/testing-bytelearn
name: path-matcher-1
pathRules:
- paths:
  - /learn/*
  service: /projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/student-cloud-storage
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
```